# I am currently trying to display data from my xampp database using Visual Basic.net but currently having a error on cmd.ExecuteReader

Tags: visual-studio

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=finalproject;Username=root;Password=")
conn.Open()
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * From Customers Where CustomerID=@CustomerID ", conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerID", txtSearch.Text)
Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
If myreader.Read Then
    lblDisplay.Text = "First Name: " & (myreader.GetValue("1").ToString & vbCrLf & "Last Name: " & (myreader.GetValue("2").ToString & vbCrLf & "Date: " & (myreader.GetValue("3").ToString & vbCrLf & "Dental Procedure: " & (myreader.GetValue("4").ToString & vbCrLf & "Price: " & (myreader.GetValue("5").ToString)))))
Else
    MessageBox.Show("No data Found")
End If
conn.Close()
```

I’m trying to get rid of the `cmd.ExecuteReader` error